# async function running in sequence WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

so I am making a small WPF app.

I am new to C# and Multithreading, I want to run certain methods in sequence but because one of the methods is Async it does not run in sequence.

```
   private async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (!OpenFile()) return; // opens a file dialog and ensure format is correct
  
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // some heavy task which I run here so that I dont freeze the UI
    });

   

}
private void TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadButton_Click(sender, e); 

    SaveCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e); // I want this line to wait for load to finish

    LoadButton_Click(sender, e); 

    ImportCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e); // I want this line to wait for the second load to finish
   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Await these calls as well, refactor your code a bit.. extract handler's content to a separate method and don't pass senders and args between handlers

```
private Task Load()
{
    if (!OpenFile()) return;

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // some heavy task which I run here so that I dont freeze the UI
    });
}

private async void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Load();
}

private async void TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Load();

    // refactor your code to not pass sender, e.. SaveCareer();
    SaveCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e);

    await Load();

    // refactor your code to not pass sender, e.. ImportCareer();
    ImportCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was doing this sequence using different buttons since I could not run it correctly that's why it has the sender but I will do that thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` to wait an async function to finish and make function `TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence` to `async Task` return type:

```
private async Task TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await LoadButton_Click(sender, e); 

    SaveCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e); // I want this line to wait for load to finish

    await LoadButton_Click(sender, e); 

    ImportCareerInfoButton_Click(sender, e); // I want this line to wait for the second load to finish
   
}
```

Comment: so I can only make the function type async void since its a button click, i tried using:
        `await Task.Run(() => Import(sender, e));` but the function import still executes without waiting for the load function to finish. I want the function to run in sequence but since load is async It doesnt

Comment: I change my answer. So you can use `await LoadButton_Click(sender, e)`

You have to make function TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence() to `async Task` to have to use `await` in its body

Comment: Be aware that an event handler method (what TheFunctionIwantToRunInSeqeuence is supposed to be) can not return a Task. It must be `async void`.